# Is it generally possible to convert CNF to Horn clauses?

Tags: satisfiability, propositional-logic

My intuition is that it is not generally possible, but I cannot think of a proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ["Renaming a Set of Clauses as a Horn Set"](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/322047.322059) Harry Lewis showed that a CNF formula could be converted to Horn form iff a particular 2-CNF formula constructed from the original formula is satisfiable.  The satisfying assignment to the 2-CNF formula tells you which literals to flip.  The 2-CNF formula can be constructed in time quadratic to the number of literals appearing in the original formula.  Faster algorithms have been published since which reduce the problem of Horn-renaming a CNF formula to linear-time if it is possible to do at all.

Comment: Interesting. So anyway it seems that the answer to the larger question is NO.